# How to animate points over a function plot in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, plot, racket

I'm making a GUI visualization for a genetic algorithm, and want to be able to plot the maximization function and the points of each generation of individuals over this function. For each generation, I want only the points to be erased, and the next ones plotted over the already existing function plot.

Using the function `plot/dc`, I'm achieving to animate each generation of individuals, plotting all the points from a list of coordinates. But this method redraw the canvas each time it runs. So I can't plot the function itself, behind the points. I could make a list of function and points for each generation, but this would be a waste of resources.

Using this code you should be able to simulate my actual state of development.

```
#lang racket

(require racket/gui plot)

(define main-window (new frame% [label "FUNCTION AND POINTS"] [width 200] [height 600]))
(define canvas-panel (new panel% [parent main-window]))
(define function-canvas (new canvas% [parent canvas-panel]))

(define (plot-points list-of-points)
  (for-each
   (λ (population)
     (plot/dc (points population
                      #:x-min 0
                      #:x-max 3
                      #:y-min 0
                      #:y-max 9
                      #:color 'red)
              (send function-canvas get-dc)
              0 0
              (- (send canvas-panel get-width) 40)
              (- (send canvas-panel get-height) 40))
     (sleep/yield 1))
   list-of-points))

(send main-window show #t)

(plot-points '(((1 8) (2 5) (2.5 2))
                 ((2 5) (1.5 6.5) (2 3))
                 ((1.5 3) (2 2) (1.5 3.5))
                 ((2 7) (0.5 1) (2 0.5))
                 ((0.5 9) (0 5) (0.5 0))
                 ((0 1) (1 4.5) (0 8.5))))
```

Note: The points above was randomly generated, and doesn't correspond to the genetic algorithm output, so there isn't a function that can match this coordinates.

I expect to plot the function graphic behind these points, to be able to see the maximization occurring.

Comment: Have you found the [_Interactive Overlays for 2D plots_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html#%28part._2d-plot-snip-interactive-overlays%29) documentation? Particularly the [`set-overlay-renderers`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html#(meth._(((lib._plot%2Fsnip..rkt)._2d-plot-snip~25)._set-overlay-renderers))) method. A [_Blog Post by Alex Harsányi_](https://alex-hhh.github.io/2018/03/interactive-overlays-with-the-racket-plot-package-update.html) has some examples if you want something to start from, although those are less animations and more mouse-interactions

Comment: When you plot the function graphic behind these points, will the function be fixed while the points change?

Comment: I have read the documentation, but struggle to adapt to the points plotting, instead of the mouse-interactions. Also, in future stages, I want to plot a 3D function with the points overlaying it, and the documentation only says about 2D. About the second comment, it's exactly what I want. If necessary, the function could even be an image on the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot being asked here. But essentially you want to put your plot on a non all-white background, that way you can put something else (in this case a function plot) in the background. You can do this with the `background-alpha` parameter.

Adding this line to your above code:

```
(plot-background-alpha 0)
```

will have the points continually build on top of each other. Since you indicated youw anted the points to move, you will also need to clear the screen between each 'frame', you can do this by changing your draw function to:

```
(define (plot-points list-of-points)
  (for-each
   (λ (population)
     (define dc (send function-canvas get-dc))
     (send dc clear)
     (plot/dc .... elided ....
              dc
              0 0
              (- (send canvas-panel get-width) 40)
              (- (send canvas-panel get-height) 40))
     (sleep/yield 1))
   list-of-points))
```

Now to draw your actual background. You could recalculate it each frame, but as you indicated that would be too slow.<sup>1</sup> So we can calculate it once, render it as an image, and redraw that each 'frame'. Say the function you want in the background is (+ (sin (* 5 x)) 3), your code would look like:

```
(define plot-func (function (λ (x) (+ (sin (* 5 x)) 3))
                            0 (* 2 pi)))

(define plot-background
  (plot-bitmap plot-func
               #:x-min 0
               #:x-max 3
               #:y-min 0
               #:y-max 9
               #:width (- (send canvas-panel get-width) 40)
               #:height (- (send canvas-panel get-height) 40)))
```

Note that `get-width` and `get-height` won't store the actual canvas's width/height until *after* the `show` method is called.

And now we need to update the draw function to draw this plot to the background:

```
(define (plot-points list-of-points)
  (for-each
   (λ (population)
     (define dc (send function-canvas get-dc))
     (send dc clear)
     (send dc draw-bitmap plot-background 0 0)
     ... elided ...
     (sleep/yield 1))
   list-of-points))
```

Putting it all together gives:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/gui plot)

(define main-window (new frame% [label "FUNCTION AND POINTS"] [width 200] [height 600]))
(define canvas-panel (new panel% [parent main-window]))
(define function-canvas (new canvas% [parent canvas-panel]))
(send main-window show #t)
(plot-background-alpha 0)

(define plot-func (function (λ (x) (+ (sin (* 5 x)) 3))
                            0 (* 2 pi)))

(define plot-background
  (plot-bitmap plot-func
               #:x-min 0
               #:x-max 3
               #:y-min 0
               #:y-max 9
               #:width (- (send canvas-panel get-width) 40)
               #:height (- (send canvas-panel get-height) 40)))

(define (plot-points list-of-points)
  (for-each
   (λ (population)
     (define dc (send function-canvas get-dc))
     (send dc clear)
     (send dc draw-bitmap plot-background 0 0)
     (plot/dc (points population
                      #:x-min 0
                      #:x-max 3
                      #:y-min 0
                      #:y-max 9
                      #:color 'red)
              dc
              0 0
              (- (send canvas-panel get-width) 40)
              (- (send canvas-panel get-height) 40))
     (sleep/yield 1))
   list-of-points))

(plot-points '(((1 8) (2 5) (2.5 2))
                 ((2 5) (1.5 6.5) (2 3))
                 ((1.5 3) (2 2) (1.5 3.5))
                 ((2 7) (0.5 1) (2 0.5))
                 ((0.5 9) (0 5) (0.5 0))
                 ((0 1) (1 4.5) (0 8.5))))
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Obviously this depends on the details of what you are calculating and how fast you want to draw it. It might actually be fast enough. ;)</sub>